# How to get Arg in Ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg, malware

I am In A deep Trouble. I am New to Reverse Engineering. I am Currently Using OLLYDBG. Now, I was Trying to Crack the Password of a .exe file using Ollydbg

Now, The EXE file which i was trying to crack was By Watching some Youtube Video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gSOKmNk-sA`

Now, Look at this Screenshot ( This is Took from Video)
[image: Here in Image You can See in CPU Main Thread, There is Something on Right Written as Arg1, Arg2, Arg3 ....]

When i Try the Same Application to Reverse on My System, I don't see any Arg1,Arg2,Arg3 kind of thing.

[image: This is My Ollydbg, when i am trying to reverse the Same EXE File]

Now, Can Anybody tell me How to get those Arg1,Arg2.... In my Panel too. Because the Password of this Executable file is Meant to be there. And The Registers are same, But i couldnt find those arg1,arg2 in Mine..

Please Help

Comment: ctrl + A        ............

Comment: The anonymous downvoter was here. Seriously, why was this downvoted?

Comment: @franz1https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Vitaly, and what is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

same as blabb's answer : hit ctrl+A